# If function that searches a column for ''text''

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, ifs

I am building a google sheet to autogenerate a report. I have a table that populates itself but I want an image to appear at the top of the page if "IN-36" Appears in column C of "Equipment" tab. I currently have this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Equipment!C6:C60="IN-36",N5,))
```

I have the image I want in cell N5, my issue is "IN-36" appears 21 rows down in the range described. This causes the image to appear 21 rows below the cell I place the formula in. Does anyone know how to make the image appear in the cell I have placed the formula?

Thanks for the help

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Equipment!C6:C60="IN-36",N5,))
```

Picture to appear in cell I placed the formula in

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=if(countif(Equipment!C6:C60,"IN-36")>0,N5,)
```